# Yarn vs npm, benefits on WSL

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Are there benefits to using Yarn over npm on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

I've read that either are a little slower because of how Bash on Windows works with the filesystem and yarn seems to have issues with Bash on Windows. Wondering if what the pros and cons may be.

Comment: I've found that `yarn` is more stable than `npm` in WSL, by stable I mean not mysteriously hanging with no visible error. There is probably a deeper cause but why spend time debugging the tooling when you have real work to do.

Answer (score 2):

Both are great on WSL, I've recently switched to Yarn and it's now my preferred choice. Install Yarn [as recommended by the Linux Install documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/) with apt-get instead of NPM to bypass a lot of the issues people seem to be having.

If you went the NVM route you can skip the Node install with:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends yarn
```

Comment: Pros and cons please

Comment: This covers most of it: https://soshace.com/yarn-package-manager-in-2019-should-we-keep-on-comparing-yarn-with-npm/